# Widget Overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm brand new to Dart and Flutter. I'm trying to overflow some Widget from their parent in a Stack widget. I ended up with something that looks like what I want, but with warnings: `A RenderConstraintsTransformBox overflowed by 50 pixels on the left.` and `A RenderConstraintsTransformBox overflowed by 50 pixels on the right.`

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: size,
          height: size,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: buildElement(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildElement() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: FractionalTranslation(
                translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
                child: buildSomeComponent(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: FractionalTranslation(
                translation: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
                child: buildSomeComponent(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSomeComponent() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.cyan,
      child: const Text(
        '[::::::::::::::::::::]',
        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        softWrap: false,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It looks looks this:
[image]

This **is** the expected result, except the warnings

The wanted result as shown is the red box being the "main" content, and the cyan boxes are kind-of tooltips.

I tried with some `OverflowBox` placed at different levels (except under `UnconstrainedBox` which messes up with the app) or `Flexible` around `Text`, but it has no effect on the caught exceptions.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When you say you're expecting the overflow, do you mean that you're trying to draw the shape in the image *without* warning?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm trying to have kind-of tooltips, like some content inside a parent, positioned relative to it, one will be on the top-left corner and the other one on the bottom-right corner. They will contain dynamic content (unknown size).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is overflowing because you are trying to put `Container` from `buildSomeComponent()` and the width is bigger than its parent `SizedBox()` of width 50. How about setting `Stack` as parent and set the size of the red box in the `Container` instead?

```
Widget buildElement() {
  return 
    Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: FractionalTranslation(
                translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
                child: buildSomeComponent(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: FractionalTranslation(
                translation: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
                child: buildSomeComponent(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello! This does not work because it takes the Stack's parent size instead of 50. I need my box to be a fixed size, and having children "oveflowing" because I need these children to behave like some tooltip to these boxes.

Comment: In image: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/GkyxsVc.png)

Comment: Apologies, how about adding Center and setting Stack as child of Center?

Comment: There was already a parent Center around the Stack unfortunately, and it seems it does not center as if the inner Stack were expanding without a surrounding SizedBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove  `UnconstrainedBox`, it will be visible (overflow text/part) by default on Stack.

```dart
  Widget buildElement() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: FractionalTranslation(
              translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
              child: buildSomeComponent(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: FractionalTranslation(
              translation: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
              child: buildSomeComponent(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can find more about [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), Align and Positioned widgets.

Comment: Hello! If I remove Unconstrained, the text overflowing is visible yes, but the alignement translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5) (minus or plus) is made regarding the parent box size, the text is not in the corner center.

Comment: In image: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/uV9Nuvt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to do what I need:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: buildMap(size),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildMap(double size) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Center(
                    child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                  ),
                  CustomMultiChildLayout(
                    delegate: CustomMultiChildLayoutDelegate(),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      LayoutId(
                        id: ComponentPosition.top,
                        child: buildSomeComponent(),
                      ),
                      LayoutId(
                        id: ComponentPosition.bottom,
                        child: buildSomeComponent(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSomeComponent() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.cyan,
      child: const Text(
        '[:::::::::::::::::::::::::::]',
        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomMultiChildLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  CustomMultiChildLayoutDelegate();

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    if (hasChild(ComponentPosition.top)) {
      final childSize = layoutChild(
        ComponentPosition.top,
        const BoxConstraints(),
      );

      positionChild(
        ComponentPosition.top,
        Offset(
          -childSize.width / 2,
          -childSize.height / 2,
        ),
      );
    }

    if (hasChild(ComponentPosition.bottom)) {
      final childSize = layoutChild(
        ComponentPosition.bottom,
        const BoxConstraints(),
      );

      positionChild(
        ComponentPosition.bottom,
        Offset(
          size.width - (childSize.width / 2),
          size.height - (childSize.height / 2),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

enum ComponentPosition {
  top,
  bottom,
}
```

I'm using `layoutChild()` with `const BoxConstraints()` to do nothing but to get the result child to offset it based on its size.

The expected result without warnings:
[image]

I'm going with this for now as it is the only solution I'm aware of, but don't hesitate to point me out a better/cleaner solution

For more context: I'm building a game with a map that will contains many of these red boxes (buildings) with positioned stuffs relative to it (build countdown, ...), and mixed with some skew/unskew and rotation/unrotate I get an isomorphic view of all of this.

[image]